# Strange behaviour or may be bug in sprintf() in c++

Tags: string, pointers, printf, cstring

I just found strange thing about `sprintf()` (c++ library function).

have a look at these two solutions

[Time limit Exceeded solution](http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/3938157)

[Accepted Solution](http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/3938145)

the only difference between them is that, I used

```
sprintf(a,"%d%c",n,'\0');
```

in TLE solution, 
in AC solution I replaced above `sprintf()` with

```
sprintf(a,"%d",n);
```

You can also observe that ACed solution took only 0.01s and 2.8MB memory 
but TLE solution took around 11.8MB
[check here](http://www.codechef.com/status/FCTRL2?sort_by=All&sorting_order=asc&language=All&status=All&handle=hkbharath&Submit=GO)

And one more thing program that gave TLE runs in 0s in [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/e.js/jMhUVJ) with extreme input data
so is it a bug in [CODECHEF](http://www.codechef.com) itself

Somebody please explain me is this a bug or some considerable unknown operation is happening here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Neither of those code snippets contains `sscanf` at all. And the first `sscanf` is obviously wrong (trying to read into a character constant?) and the second one is questionable (is `n` a pointer?)

Comment: sorry the issue was about `sprintf()` not `sscanf()`.
and n is a integer variable which is always less than 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the differences in the codes is **not** with `sscanf`, but with `sprintf`. A diff of the code explains:

```
--- ac.c        2014-05-24 14:31:18.074977661 -0500
+++ tle.c       2014-05-24 14:30:52.270650109 -0500
@@ -4,7 +4,7 @@

string mul(string m, int n){
char a[4];
-sprintf(a,"%d",n);
+sprintf(a,"%d%c",n,'\0');
int l1 = strlen(a);
//printf("len : %d\n",l1);
int l2 = m.length();
```

Second, by explicitly packing the string with `%c` and `'\0'`, you are reducing the size of the integer that can be stored in a by 1. You need to check the return of sprintf. man printf:

**Upon successful return, these functions return the number of characters printed (not including the trailing '\0' used to end output to strings).**

In your case you are most likely writing beyond the end of your `a[4]` string and are experiencing undefined results. With `a[4]` you have space for only `999\0`. When you explicitly add `%c` + `'\0'`, you reduce that to `99\0\0`. If your number exceeds 99, then sprintf will write beyond the end of the string because you are explicitly packing an additional '\0'. In the original case `sprintf(a,"%d",n);` 999 can be stored without issue relying on sprintf to append '\0' as a[3].

test with `n = 9999`, sprintf will still store the number in a, but will return `5` which exceeds the space available `a[4]`, meaning that the behavior of your code is a dice-roll at that point.

Comment: ok i agree with your idea but why do I get TLE it should be Wrong Answer. Or is this unusual behaviours is caused by adding extra null character in the string ??

Comment: The undefined behavior means that your code could do anything from print out the integer properly to segfault (it's just undefined). I do not know what the values of `n` are, but in your case I suspect they are in the 100 range. That means that at any point after sprintf returns more than 4, anything can happen later on in your code (like a read process reading beyond the end of a boundary and sucking up an additional 11.8 M of stuff you didn't expect. (it's just undefined). Insuring that you are not overwriting the end of `a[4]` is a good start to prevent surprises.